# I need to know what IN(@sub) means in this statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was hoping that somebody could help me out.  I'm new to TSQL and have come across the following code:

```
FROM
    Job_List j1 
INNER JOIN 
    Item_List i1 ON j1.Control_No = i1.Control_No
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE,j1.Settlement_Date_Actual) >= CONVERT(DATE,@sday)
    AND CONVERT(DATE,j1.Settlement_Date_Actual) <= CONVERT(DATE,@eday)
    AND j1.Supplier_No IN(@supplier)
    AND CASE
          WHEN j1.Sub_Client IS NULL THEN '(BLANK)'
          WHEN j1.Sub_Client = '' THEN '(BLANK)' 
          ELSE J1.Sub_Client 
    END IN(@sub)
```

***can anyone explain to me what the IN(@sub) is doing?

Comment: What part you have trouble with? `IN` or `@something`?

Answer (score 1):

The expression is:

```
CASE WHEN j1.Sub_Client IS NULL THEN '(BLANK)'
     WHEN j1.Sub_Client = '' THEN '(BLANK)' 
     ELSE J1.Sub_Client 
END IN (@sub)
```

You are not asking about the `case`, so let's take the example `J1.Sub_Client IN (@sub)`

It actually means:

```
    J1.Sub_Client = @sub
```

The person who wrote it might have thought they could put a comma delimited list in `@sub`.  In that case, the person would have mistakenly thought that the following are equivalent (assuming `@sub` is 'a,b,c'):

```
J1.Sub_Client in (@sub)
J1.Sub_Client in ('a', 'b', 'c')
J1.Sub_Client = 'a' or J1.Sub_Client = 'b' or J1.Sub_Client = 'c'
```

The last two are equivalent.  The first tests for equality between `J1.Sub_Client` and the string `'a,b,c'` -- one value, not three.

Comment: What about the `IN(@sub)` at the end. I think that's the part the OP is interested in.

Comment: It's possible there are 2 table variables, @ sub, and @ supplier, as we don't have full code from the OP.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin . . . The answer is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

@sub sounds like it is a `table variable`, and the IN(@sub) is checking the result of the `case` statement right before it.

To elaborate,

The last line is part of a case statement.

```
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE,j1.Settlement_Date_Actual) >= CONVERT(DATE,@sday)
    AND CONVERT(DATE,j1.Settlement_Date_Actual) <= CONVERT(DATE,@eday)
    AND j1.Supplier_No IN(@supplier)
    AND CASE -- Begin case statement
          WHEN j1.Sub_Client IS NULL THEN '(BLANK)'
          WHEN j1.Sub_Client = '' THEN '(BLANK)' 
          ELSE J1.Sub_Client 
    END IN(@sub) -- Case statement ends, and the result is the value checked against the @sub table variable
```

Simplified,

```
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE,j1.Settlement_Date_Actual) >= CONVERT(DATE,@sday)
    AND CONVERT(DATE,j1.Settlement_Date_Actual) <= CONVERT(DATE,@eday)
    AND j1.Supplier_No IN(@supplier)
    AND 'SomeString' IN(@sub)
```

In this case 'SomeString' is determined by the CASE Statement preceding it, and uses either `J1.Sub_Client` or the value `'(BLANK)'`

**Update**

Well the IN(@sub) syntax is wrong for table variables, thanks to a comment. This must be a scalar variable. Same concept applies, though, as I've explained above. Difference being IN here really refers to one value, not many possible ones.

The reason IN(@sub) works is because IN works with one parameter, such as

```
IN('StackOverflow')
```

When IN is used with only one value, it's equivalent to writing

```
= 'StackOverflow'
```

since IN compares the full value (and not a string Contains type of operation) on the left side of the `=` sign to each parameter in the right side.

Comment: If `@sub` were a table variable, the syntax would be `in (select sub from @sub)`.